# ASP.NET WebAPI - how to create an abstract layer for multiple services

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, workflow

Alright, so assuming I am making a fancy web store.

I have a payment provider (say, paypal) which requires the user to sign into paypal website, confirm the credentials and then to redirect him into my website.

So basically the code behind that would look like this:

```
class PaymentManager
{
   public string AcceptPayment(Payment payment)
   {
      //return redirect url
   }

   public bool ConfirmPayment(string paymentToken)
   {
      //if token is valid the payment succeded
   }
}
```

So basically the usage of this manager from my controller maps into 2 controller methods (each requiring an individual request).

Now, assuming I have a different payment manager, which requires 3 methods being sequentially executed instead of 2. Something like:

```
class AnotherPaymentManager
{
   public string AcceptPayment(Payment payment)
   {
      //return validation redirect url
   }

   public string ValidatePayment(string validationCode)
   {
      //return redirect url
   }

   public bool ConfirmPayment(string paymentToken)
   {
      //if token is valid, confirm payment
   }
}
```

Now this class' usage maps into 3 controller methods (we need the client to execute the `Accept` method to declare payment, then to execute the `Validate` method to validate it and after all to execute the `Confirm` method to make sure the server has accepted it).

**The question is:** provided these managers have different API usage scenarios to do the same thing (as shown above), is there a way to make an abstract layer between them and the controller? I mean something like:

```
interface IPaymentManager
{
    void MakePayment(); //this controls the payment methods flow 
                        //Something like (Accept -> Confirm) in the former case
                        //and (Accept -> Validate -> Confirm) in the latter
}
```

I am doing this in ASP.NET WebAPI 2, but I think it may apply to MVC as well.

Comment: You can add "bool NeedValidatePayment" property to your interface. Only providers which implement ValidatePayment will return true for it. That's fine unless all your payment providers are very different. It's not good to add a bunch of such properties.

Comment: When you say each PaymentManager method requires a separate request, are you referring to a separate request from your application to the payment provider (Paypal)? Or are they separate requests between the front end and back end of your application?

Comment: @M.Carlson the latter: user has to validate things in his own browser so these are the points where I'm losing control over the workflow.

Comment: @bashis does my answer, answer your question? I can change it if not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, when a user creates a transaction they are redirected to the payment provider (with a redirect url in the response). Once there they confirm their credentials which returns them to your fancy web store (with a confirmation token provided by the payment provider). If that token is valid then the transaction was successful. Also each of those actions require a separate endpoint in your controller.

If those assumptions are correct, I would say it is not necessary, or even recommended, to create an abstraction here. Also there is response data (validationCode, paymentToken, etc.) from the payment provider which your PaymentManger functions and controller endpoints are dependent on in order to proceed in the process.

In my experience, trying to abstract too early can make more work for you down the road. Without more information (more implementations of payment provider clients) you might make abstractions that are too specific - which can not be used for different PaymentManager types you add later.

However, if you already posses this data (validationCode, etc.), then you could abstract here, but I would still say it is unnecessary, and potentially a waste of time.

If you are determined to abstract here, then you can implement your interface in each of your PaymentManager classes. Having each PaymentManger implement the MakePayment function which would call the respective PaymentManager functions.

Again, I would not recommend abstracting here. It doesn't make sense, and really won't be that helpful in my opinion. Wait until you implement a few more PaymentManager classes. Then you will be able to more accurately see the patterns between the different types of PaymentMangers and abstract those patterns out.

If my understanding of the problem was not correct, let me know where I misunderstood the problem, and I will try to answer it again.

On a side note, I would recommend looking into [asynchronous functions and the await operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx), if you haven't already and are making calls to an external API.

Hope this helps.